# Smart Caret in Eclipse stops working for some files

Tags: eclipse, caret

I am using Eclipse and I am coding java. I really like the "Smart Caret" option for the Home and End buttons since it allows you to go the start and end of a line but not past any whitespaces. Also the Home key will take you to the start of a comment, rather than the start of the line. And you can cycle through different positions with these keys. And this is how the editor was by default, from installation.

However one thing that has happened a few times now is that when I am writing code in the editor, this functionality just vanishes. It is seemingly random when it happens and the weirdest part, I think, is that it is file specific. So all of a sudden when I am writing, the Home and End keys start taking me to the very start and end of the line I am on. It is as if I am accidentally pressing some hotkey to disable these Smart Carets for the specific file.

It does not help to disable and re-enable the Smart Caret option in Preferences. And beyond that I do not really know what to do. Is this a bug? It is incredibly annoying when it happens. Being used to things working one way, then having them spontaneously change and then again having them back to the default when I am editing a different file.

Comment: This happened in one of my workspaces. Eclipse 2019-03 (4.11.0)
Did you find a solution?

Comment: FYI: After exiting and restarting Eclipse, it started to work again.

Comment: Happening too in 2019-06, same solution as proposed by @DavidBalažic works

Comment: Still happening in 2020-06 with latest PyDev, and restarting still works

Comment: Still happens in 2022-03 and restarting still works.